# Class private member - array accessing failed

Tags: c++, class, oop, private, member

So I have this code in C++ which is just exercise in learning C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int random(int max){
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % max;
}


class player{
    public:
        player(){
            liv = 5;
            mun = 3;
        }
        void Rename(char name[]){
            name = name;
        }
        void set_group(player pl[]){
            pl = pl;
        }
        void fire(){
            if (liv > 0 and mun){
                mun -= 1;
                int hit = random(10);
                printf("%d: ", hit);
                printf("%s", pl[hit].get_name());
                if (hit < 5 and pl[hit].live()){
                    pl[hit].hit();
                    printf("Player %s hit player %s!", name, pl[hit].get_name());
                }
            }
        }
        bool live(){
            return liv;
        }
        void hit(){
            liv -= 1;
        }
        char * get_name(){
            return name;
        }
    private:
        int liv, mun;
        char name[100];
        player *pl;
};


main(){
    player pl[5];
    char str[100];
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<5;x++){
        sprintf(str, "%d", x + 1);
        pl[x].Rename(str);
        pl[x].set_group(pl);
    }
    pl[0].fire();
}
```

Compiler (`TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32-bit`) compiles code and returns 0 warnings and 0 errors.
When I run the program I get message: `classes.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.`

I debugged it and found that line `printf("%s", pl[hit].get_name());` is a problem (actually it's a debug line and line after that was actually problem, but it's the same thing). I also *think* that accessing to pl is problem.

I'm relatively new to C and C++ (especially to C+) and my main programming language is Python so don't laugh too much at my mistakes.

Comment: mistake 1: you should not call `srand(time(NULL));` inside your random function, because if you call it many times within a second you will always get the same random number. Instead you should set the seed only once.

Comment: `pl = pl;` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `pl = pl;` variable names comes for free in c++, don't recycle the `pl` name for a member variable and for a parameter; which `pl` is assigned to which `pl` in this instruction? I don't know, and don't want to know it: just use a different name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things I would suggest you to change:

- You should not set the seed each time you roll a new random number. Try to call your random function inside a loop many times and you will see that you get the same number each time.
- Use `std::vector` instead of c-style arrays
- Use `std::string` instead of chars
- If you use `std::cout` instead of `printf` you do not have to take care of formatting by yourself.
- Your `player` constructor does not set the name. As a result it is possible to create a player in an incomplete state (ie. without name)
- In the constructor it is more efficient to use a initializer list
- Does the player really have to know in what group he is? I would suggest to change it, because atm you are mixing what a single player is with how they interact with each other.
- What if the player group has only a single player? Your code cannot handle this case.
- With your code a player can hit himself. Not sure if this is what you want ;)

In total, it could look like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib> // for rand()

void init_random(){srand(time(0));}
int random(int max){return rand() % max;}

class player{
public:
    player(std::string name) : liv(5),mun(3),name(name){}
    void Rename(std::string newname){name = newname;}
    bool live(){return liv;}
    void hit(){liv -= 1;}
    void fire(){mun -= 1;}
    std::string get_name(){return name;}
private:
    int liv, mun;
    std::string name;
};

class player_group{
public:
    void addPlayer(const player& p){players.push_back(p);}
    void fire(int i){
        // avoid wrong input
        if (i>=0 && i<players.size() && players.size()>1){
            players[i].fire();
            int other = i;
            // avoid player hitting himself
            while (other == i){other = random(players.size());}
            players[other].hit();
            std::cout << "Player " 
                      << players[i].get_name() 
                      << " hits player " 
                      << players[other].get_name() 
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<player> players;
};

int main() {
    init_random();
    player_group pg;
    pg.addPlayer(player("Peter"));
    pg.addPlayer(player("Paul"));
    pg.fire(0);
}
```

Since C++11 there are better random generators. If you need high-quality randomness you should use them instead of `rand()` which has [some issues](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). However, in this case imho `rand()` is just fine.

Also note that in my code the player group "owns" the players. What I mean is that `addPlayer()` calls `push_back()` which adds a copy to the vector. If this is not what you want, you might consider to change the `player_group` to hold a `std::vector<player*>` to avoid the copying.

Comment: This `void Rename(std::string name){name = name;}` is a no-op as well. Note that the only place where you can get off with something like this is the constructor initializing its sub-objects e.g. `player(std::string name) : name(name)` does indeed what you expect.

Comment: @dxiv hm I guess you are right. I got rid of my java habbit of writing `this->` all over the place but somehow I must have missed this point.

Comment: I think you forgot to include ``stdlib.h``, I included it but I'm still getting 3 errors: Line 45: ``[Error] 'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type``, Line 28: ``[Error] 'players' was not declared in this scope``, Line 31: ``[Error] 'players' was not declared in this scope``

Comment: @knowledge yes, some includes got lost while copy&paste, I will fix it

Answer (score 3):

This does actually nothing.

```
void Rename(char name[]){
    name = name;
}
```

In fact, it is equivalent to

```
void Rename(char *p){
    p = p;
}
```

You want

```
void Rename(char name[]){
    strcpy(this->name, name);
}
```

but even better would be to use non-conflicting names and add some error checking.

**[ EDIT ]** The same issue exists with "set_group(player pl[])" - thanks @Kevin for catching that.

Comment: "This does actually nothing"...what do you mean?

Comment: @tobi303 The "name" argument hides the "name" class member. The end result in this case is a no-op, see the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for help but I'm still getting the error (does it work for you?).

Comment: You have the same issue in `set_group`